# Active Record join where all joined records DO NOT match query string

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Recipe` that contains many `Ingredients`.

```rb
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ingredients
end
```

```rb
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

I can find recipes that contain any ingredient whose name is similar to a search query, `q`.

```rb
Recipe.joins(:ingredients).where('lower(ingredients.name) LIKE ?', "%#{q}%")
```

This results in the following output.

```rb
Recipe.search('cod')
  Recipe Load (0.9ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "recipes".* FROM "recipes" INNER JOIN "ingredients" ON "ingredients"."recipe_id" = "recipes"."id" WHERE (lower(ingredients.name) LIKE '%cod%' OR lower(recipes.name) LIKE '%cod%')
 => 
[#<Recipe:0x0000000114812300
  id: 227,
  name: "Fish Tacos",
  steps:
   "<div>To make beer batter: In a large bowl, combine flour, cornstarch, baking powder, and salt. Blend egg and beer, then quickly stir into the flour mixture (don't worry about a few lumps).</div><div><br>To make white sauce: In a medium bowl, mix together yogurt and mayonnaise. Gradually stir in fresh lime juice until consistency is slightly runny. Season with jalapeno, capers, oregano, cumin, dill, and cayenne.</div><div><br>Heat oil in deep-fryer to 375 degrees F (190 degrees C).</div><div><br>Dust fish pieces lightly with flour. Dip into beer batter, and fry until crisp and golden brown. Drain on paper towels. Lightly fry tortillas; not too crisp. To serve, place fried fish in a tortilla, and top with shredded cabbage, and white sauce.</div>",
  desc: nil,
  created_at: Sat, 24 Dec 2022 16:03:44.122092000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sat, 24 Dec 2022 16:05:53.886182000 UTC +00:00>]
```

The SQL

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT "recipes".* FROM "recipes" INNER JOIN "ingredients" ON "ingredients"."recipe_id" = "recipes"."id" WHERE (lower(ingredients.name) LIKE '%cod%' OR lower(recipes.name) LIKE '%cod%')
```

How could I do the opposite though? If I want to search for any Recipe that **doesn't** contain Cheese, Beef, Etc, how do I change the ActiveRecord joins where NOT for EVERY associated record.

In other words, how do I change the query to return `Recipes` where NO ingredient has a name that matches the query `q`?

With the current approach, I've been trying I get back EVERY `Recipe` because every recipe has at least one ingredient that doesn't match the query.

```rb
Recipe.joins(:ingredients).where('ingredients.name NOT LIKE ?', 'cheese')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In SQL you'd use `select * from recipe where not exists (select * from ingredients where recipe_id = recipe.id and name like '%cheese%')`

Comment: @MatBailie I used this with hardcoding the string and was able to achieve the functionality I wanted(although admittedly not as clean as if I could figure out how to make this query with ActiveRecord alone). 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Recipe.where(
 Ingredient.where('ingredients.name LIKE %?%',  'cheese')
           .where(Ingredient.arel_table[:recipe_id].eq(Recipe.arel_table[:id]))
           .arel
           .exist
           .not
)
```